# Sorting a List by two variables

Tags: c#, list, sorting, coding-style

Got a List of "ClientContacts" --- which have EITHER a LastName (in the case of a human) OR an EntityName (in the case of a general-use contact, such as techsupport@mycompany.com).

What I want to do is SORT this List alphabetically by LastName, and in the case where no LastName exists (in other words, an EntityName exists), to treat that EntityName as a LastName, and continue the Sort as if it were a LastName.

So that the **desired result** looks like:

1. Bond James
2. Customer Support
3. Gates Bill
4. Tech Support
5. Williams Robin

---

This causes a crash, because it runs into some ClientContacts that don't have a LastName.

```
clientContactList.Sort(
    delegate(ClientContact c1, ClientContact c2) 
        { return c1.LastName.CompareTo(c2.LastName); });
```

And the following allows me to get through without crashing, and it sorts it by ClientContact EntityName's first, and THEN LastNames:

```
            list.Sort(delegate(ClientContact c1, ClientContact c2) {
            try
            {
                return c1.LastName.CompareTo(c2.LastName);
            }
            catch
            {
                try
                {
                    return c1.EntityName.CompareTo(c2.LastName);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return c1.EntityName.CompareTo(c2.EntityName);
                }

            }
        });
```

resulting in:

1. Customer Support
2. Tech Support
3. Bond James
4. Gates Bill
5. Williams Robin

---

How can I get my list sorted to look like the above desired result?

Comment: When you say "doesn't have," do you mean the value is null? Or is an empty string also possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this comparison instead:

```
(c1.LastName ?? c1.EntityName).CompareTo(c2.LastName ?? c2.EntityName)
```

Comment: Hooray for null coalescing operators :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use LINQ, you can do it like this:

```
var sortedList = list.OrderBy( x => x.LastName ?? x.EntityName );
```

Comment: sortedList is a bad name, it's not a list, it's IEnumerable<T>

Comment: Oh, Carl.  Relax with your bad self.  I see your point, but "enumerable" is just such a mouthful.  Think of it as using "list" in a loser, more natural sense.  I wouldn't name a property or method that way, but an automatic local variable...loosen up.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
list.Sort(delegate(ClientContact c1, ClientContact c2)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c1.LastName) ?
        c1.LastName.CompareTo(c2.LastName) :
        c1.EntityName.CompareTo(c2.LastName);         
});
```